# How to Display Message of the Day Through Drupal View

Tags: views

i have created content type name "Message of the Day". each content of the content type ("Message of the Day") should be automatically change and display one content each day. how to do in the drupal view?

**for Example**

1. A bird in the hand is worth two in the bush
2. A cat may look at a king
3. A chain is only as strong as its weakest link
4. A change is as good as a rest

the above contents are added in Message of the Day content type. **through views** i want to display one content each day.